# Why function can't be redeclared but common variable can?

Tags: php, function, loops, fatal-error

```
php -a
Interactive mode enabled
php >  function sum(){
php {         $total = 0;
php {         $varArray = func_get_args();
php {         foreach ($varArray as $var){
php {             $totals += $var;
php {         }
php {         return $total;
php {     }
php >  function sum(){
php {         $total = 0;
php {         $varArray = func_get_args();
php {         foreach ($varArray as $var){
php {             $total += $var;
php {         }
php {         return $total;
php {     }
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare sum() (previously declared in php shell code:2) in php shell code on line 8
php > $b=3;    
php > $b=5;    
php > echo $b;    
5
```

In the interactive mode of php,i input sum function wrong,it was found that the mistaken can be fixed via re-input.
For varable b ,it can be redeclared for any times ,there is no PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare for varable b here.
What is the reason for the design that function can't be redeclared ,common varable can be redeclared?
Is it harmful or dangerous or difficult for function can  be redeclared in php?
Please show me some examples for harmful or dangerous or difficult.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a method of re-declaring functions (not counting extensions like [Runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)) - you'll need to edit the original.

Comment: You are in interactive mode. exit and start again

Comment: Better to code a `tst.php` file and run it as `>php tst.php` then if you make a mistake you just need to edit the file and correct any mistakes and then run it again